# How to avoid or redirect https calls to my website?

Tags: apache, http, https

I have a website and I realized that when a link to it comes from a https website, like web.whatsapp.com it throws an error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The shared link is full http://www.example.com but when using web whatsapp, for example, it always comes with https

How can I redirect those calls to http?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not redirect an HTTPS to HTTP without running a complete and fully working HTTPS server (including server certificate) on the same IP address your HTTP server is running on.

The SSL/TLS connection needs to be fully established before you can send any data to the client to redirect it. But if you have a working HTTPS server you could also server your web site via HTTPS and not redirect to HTTP.

Comment: I don't have one :/ I guess I should just complain to whatsapp then :P Thanks